# How does Ui-router inject the code into Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How does the Angular UI-router work? I am talking about code injection. Like in my body tag I have

```
<body ng-app="myWebApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Now in my app.js I have something like

```
.state("login", {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "views/login.html",
    controller: "loginController"
})
```

and then I have login.html

Now when Angular starts to render the page does it do something like this?

```
<body ng-app="vehicoWebApp" class="ng-scope">
    <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>Hello there</body>
    </html>
</body>
```

OR

```
<body ng-app="myWebApp">
        <body>Hello there</body>
</body>
```

How does this work?

Comment: Why the heck do you have `html` inside `body` and `body` inside `body`? The correct hierarchy should be `html` -> `body` and `head`, with `head` first, then `body` at the same level of `head` (child of `html`). There should be **Exactly** one `html`, one `head` and one `body` with the correct hierarchy

Comment: Also consider keeping the `javascript` tag at least please

Comment: It's just there for representational purpose @Zorgatone . I want to know the exact behavior of Angular UI router?

Comment: I don't have an answer for that, but please fix the `html` code. Your code example is incorrect

Comment: Added @Zorgatone. And why the downvote?

Comment: The example is not incorrect. It's there for the representational purpose. Until and unless someone sees it's incorrect how the hell are they suppose to correct it?

Comment: can you post us the login.html page?

Comment: I don't know. Anyway your html code should look something like this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki.

You'll need some directive on an element representing the view, you can't have a `body` inside `body` or `html` inside `body`

Comment: I don't think that is necessary @valepu. I am trying to understand a concept. Content shouldn't matter

Comment: @Zorgatone that looks correct so my login.html and all the other html's shouldn't have a <html> tag right? and how m I suppose to load a page level css? Should all CSSS required go in the head of the index.html

Comment: Yes, head and scripts/styles should all be in the index.html

Comment: Just keep the inner template contents in a separate template.html file (content that would go inside the body/view tag/directive)